# Failure of \if condition inside \titlecontents

Tags: table-of-contents, conditionals, titlesec, titletoc

I need to add some word before contentslabel in `toc` by some condition using `titletoc`.

```
\documentclass[]{report}
\usepackage{titlesec, titletoc}

\newif{\ifappendix}


\titlecontents{section}% <section-type>
[2em]% <left>
{}% <above-code>
{\ifappendix \appendixname~\fi\thecontentslabel\ }% <numbered-entry-format>
{}% <numberless-entry-format>
{\titlerule*[0.75pc]{.}\contentspage}% <filler-page-format>\\

\titleformat{\section}[block]
    {\hspace{\parindent}}
    {\ifappendix\appendixname~\fi\thesection}
    {1em}{}    

\begin{document}

\tableofcontents

\section{One}

\appendixtrue

\section{Two}

\end{document}
```

As one can see from `MWE` the condition inside `\titlecontents` does not work (I expected red word in picture), but the same time it does work with `\titleformat` macro.

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When the table of contents is being typeset, `\ifappendix` returns false. You need to pass `\appendixtrue` also to the `.toc` file.

```
\documentclass[]{report}
\usepackage{titlesec, titletoc}

\newif{\ifappendix}

\titlecontents{section}% <section-type>
[2em]% <left>
{}% <above-code>
{\ifappendix \appendixname~\fi\thecontentslabel\ }% <numbered-entry-format>
{}% <numberless-entry-format>
{\titlerule*[0.75pc]{.}\contentspage}% <filler-page-format>\\

\titleformat{\section}[block]
    {\hspace{\parindent}}
    {\ifappendix\appendixname~\fi\thesection}
    {1em}{}    

\begin{document}

\tableofcontents

\section{One}

\appendixtrue
\addtocontents{toc}{\protect\appendixtrue}

\section{Two}

\end{document}
```

[image]